# Vim find in files shortcut from command

Tags: vim

Hi I use vimgrep to find text in the project.

However its a little slow because i have to write this each time:

```
vimgrep /text/ **/*.* | cwindow
```

Is there any way to map it in for example C-shift-F and show the text box.

After that when I hit enter it will execute the vimgrep commands.

That will save much time

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Vim is highly customizable (which is one big reason for its popularity), so there are several possibilities to provide a shortcut:

#### incomplete mapping

A mapping does not necessarily contain a complete command. You can just prepare the command-line and leave the cursor in a certain spot, so that you can fill out the rest and trigger the (Ex) command with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For example:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>f :vimgrep // **/*.* <Bar> cwindow<Home><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right>
```

The trailing keys position the cursor in between the `//`, so you can fill in `text`, and then execute the command.

Note: Your suggested `<C-S-f>` mapping would be the same as `<C-f>` (an unfortunate limitation in the current implementation), and therefore override a useful built-in command. I've instead used `<Leader>f` (where the default for that key is <kbd>\</kbd>; cp. `:help <Leader>`).

#### custom command

This is already nice, but assuming we'll never have a need to edit the other parts of the command, we can shorten this to a custom command, e.g. `:FindText`:

```
command! -nargs=1 FindText vimgrep /<args>/ **/*.* | cwindow
```

With this, you can search via `:FindText text`. If you still prefer a mapping, this would become

```
:nnoremap <Leader>f :FindText<Space>
```

Other benefits of custom commands are that these are easier to recall from the command-line history (as they are different from other `:vimgrep` commands you might use), and you're building a library of higher-level editing commands, which over time can be reused to build even more higher-level commands, which makes your editing more efficient.